# Laravel parent model deletion doesn't fire up child model deleting event

Tags: laravel, events, model, laravel-5.4

I'm using laravel 5.4. I have a project model as parent and project_images model as child and here is the child model:

```
Schema::create('project_images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('file', 100);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

so as expected whenever i delete a project all of its images records will be deleted as well. Then i created a deleting event in **images** model like this:

```
protected $events = [
    'deleted' => ProjectImageDeleting::class
];
```

If i delete the image itself then this event also fires up but if i delete the project, then no.

**My Question**

How should i make this works that when i delete the parent, the child event also fires up? Am i missing something? *(I already have event and listener and the code in listener works when i delete the image)*

**Update**

I removed that line in migration and changed the project model to this:

```
namespace AliMHZ;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProjectImage::class);
    }

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::deleting(function($project) {
            $project->images()->delete();
        });
    }
}
```

and this is my image model:

```
namespace AliMHZ;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use AliMHZ\Events\ProjectImageDeleting;

class ProjectImage extends Model
{
    protected $events = [
        'deleting' => ProjectImageDeleting::class
    ];
    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }
}
```

and event:

```
namespace AliMHZ\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use AliMHZ\ProjectImage;

class ProjectImageDeleting
{
    use Dispatchable,
        InteractsWithSockets,
        SerializesModels;

    public $image;
    public function __construct(ProjectImage $image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
    }
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

and finally here is the listener:

```
namespace AliMHZ\Listeners;

use AliMHZ\Events\ProjectImageDeleting;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ProjectImageDeletingListener
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }
    public function handle(ProjectImageDeleting $event)
    {
        \Log::info("File to be deleted: " . $event->image->file);
    }
}
```

After these changes, when i delete project, all its images also will be deleted but the image event still doesn't fire up but if delete the image only then the event works. I'm testing this in laravel tinker and everytime i change any model i exit tinker and lunch it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the `$table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects')->onDelete('cascade');` the deletion is done on a database level, and as thus model events are not being triggered.

To have all the related model events trigger you would have to write code for this in the models manually.

```php
<?php

class Project extends Eloquent
{
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->has_many('Image');
    }

    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($project) {
             // This will trigger the ProjectImageDeleting event.
             $project->images()->delete();
        });
    }
}
```

---

**Edited to answer edited part of question**

Could you try the following

```php
namespace AliMHZ;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProjectImage::class);
    }

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::deleting(function($project) {
            $project->images()->get()->each(function ($image) {
                  $image->delete();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

If you want to read more about why this is happening you can read about it on [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2536).

Comment: Thanks for answer, i did the same but nothing happens.

Comment: @Ali could it be that you are using the deleted event? By that time the model has already been removed in the database, and your code might act differently then you think.

Comment: @NicklasKervinFrank i updated my question to show latest changes, would you please take a look? thanks